# How can I modify the name of a file originally defined in a recorded macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded a macro that filters through and reformats data from a report. I would like to automatically save the file but the name of the report needs to change each time it is ran. The structure of the file name is "190509_Sample_Set1_TFB" where date, set#, and initials change.

As I originally recorded the macro I just highlighted the piece of information that I needed directly from the report and used it to save as the file name.

```
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Working List Source: 190509_Sample_Set1_TFB"
    ChDir "S:\shared\5. QC\QC Samples\2019"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "S:\shared\5. QC\QC Samples\2019\190509_Sample_Set1_QC_TFB.xlsx", _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

My work around has been to include a user prompt to manually enter the file name but it would be nice to have it totally automated.

Comment: Simply use string concatenation to create the filename - but where do you get *date*, *set* and *Initials* from?

Answer (score 0):

You can set something like below and change "Your Initial" to a variable or Cell location like Range("A1")

```
"S:\shared\5. QC\QC Samples\" & Year(Now) & "\" & Format(Now, "yymmdd") & "_Sample_Set1_QC_" & "Your Initial" & ".xlsx"
```